# Can't SSH into Google Cloud VM, How to debug?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a VNC server running on a google cloud VM. It had a weird error 'Cannot open Chrome, out of memory'. So I restarted.

The VNC server is a docker container set to auto restart.

Now no matter how many times I 'reset' or 'stop' the instance, the SSH login just loops forever and times out. And The VNC server 404s.

How do I debug this if I cannot ssh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to check what's going on on you VM go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on NAME_OF_YOUR_VM -> at the `VM instance details` find section **Logs** and click on `Serial port 1 (console)` and there you'll find a lot of log messages where you should search mainly for "No space left" errors. As you can find at the documentation [Handling the "Could not connect, retrying..." error](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser#couldnotconnecterror):

> The boot disk of the instance has run out of free space. When the
>   connection is established, the guest environment updates the
>   ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file with the public SSH key used for the
>   current session. If the disk runs out of free space, the update fails.
>   To identify issues with disk space, **check the serial console output of
>   the instance and look for "No space left" errors**.

If you found "No space left" error messages follow these instructions:

> - [Resize](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd) the boot persistent disk of the instance to increase its size.    If the operating system image used by the instance [supports
>     automatic    resizing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_partitions), this is the easiest option because the
>     operating system    automatically resizes the root partition to match
>     the new size after    the instance is restarted.
> - If you know which files are using the disk space, [create a startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) that deletes the unnecessary files and frees space for the
>     instance to start. Restart the instance so that the script executes
>     and cleans the files. Be careful to use the correct command and
>     delete the correct files. After your instance starts and you are able 
>     to connect to the instance through SSH, set the startup-script
>     metadata item back so it does not continue to delete the files.
> - For information about how to access the instance's disk, see [General tips for using Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting).

and in some cases you should follow Recovering an inaccessible instance or a full boot disk guide:

> **If an instance is completely out of disk space** or if it is not running
>   a Linux guest environment, **then automatically resizing your root
>   filesystem isn't possible**, even after you've increased the size of the
>   persistent disk that backs it. If you can't connect to your instance,
>   or your boot disk is full and you can't resize it, **you must create a
>   new instance and recreate the boot disk from a snapshot to resize it**.

step by step instructions you can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#inaccessible_instance).

**If your problem isn't related to disk space** you can **try debug it with a [troubleshooting script](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-ssh-diagnostic-sh)** for Compute Engine to identify issues with SSH login/accessibility of your Linux based instance that Google provides.

In addition, you can **try to connect to your VM via Serial console** by following this [guide](https://medium.com/google-cloud/resolving-getting-locked-out-of-a-compute-engine-85800251890b), but keep in mind that:

> The interactive serial console does not support IP-based access
>   restrictions such as IP whitelists. If you enable the interactive
>   serial console on an instance, clients can attempt to connect to that
>   instance from any IP address.

more details you can find in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console).

Feel free to provide more details in your question and I'll update my answer.